# Database trigger and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, caching, transactions, triggers

I've met a scenario:

1. `save` or `update` some data in a target table by hibernate
2. there is a trigger on the target table which will be executed before `insert` or `update` operations of the target table
3. `select` out this record by hibernate

But I find that the fields which have been modified by the trigger are not really fetched out.
Is this related with transactions commit of Hibernate (flush() has already be called) or Hibernate cache? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be caused by both the first (session) or second (e.g. ehcache) caches. To re-read the entity, you'll need to call session.refresh().

From [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-loading) (at the bottom of the section)

> It is possible to re-load an object and all its collections at any
>   time, using the refresh() method. This is useful when database
>   triggers are used to initialize some of the properties of the object.

```
sess.save(cat);
sess.flush(); //force the SQL INSERT
sess.refresh(cat); //re-read the state (after the trigger executes)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can map properties as [generated values](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated). These values always come from the database and can't be stored. Hibernate automatically loads these values in a subsequent query after inserting or updating the database.