# need best solution to avoid infinite loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops

so I have this data in table :

```
|ID | key | flag |
| 1 | a   |  1   |
| 2 | b   |  0   |
|........
```

so when the user of my web app need to use the "key" data , they need to look up the data with flag "1" which means available to use whereas flag "0" means being used

I make this request with jquery to look up available "key" data to the server , server will respon with "1" if the data available (means there's data with flag 1 ) , so the data will be picked up and marked as 0 (being used ), when the user done using key , the data will be marked as 1

the problem is when theres no data with flag 1 , the jquery will keep sending request untill the flag 1 is available , and it end up in infinite loops

I need the best solution of this

Comment: Put some codes that you've already tried.

Comment: Why not send a different response to indicate that there's nothing available?

Comment: ... or add a condition when sending your jquery requests?

Comment: do you think the best approach is doing loop in client side or server side?

Comment: @andrewsi yes I did that , when nothing available server response with 0, when the response is 0 , the jquery start sending request again till the flag 1 is available, that's what Im doing, so is there any better way like server will tell the client /browser if the flag is available ?? so I dont have to do this looping

Comment: @maia: use long polling/comet so the server can tell the client that data's avaialble, or THROTTLE your requests, so that if there's no 1's, the next request will be paused by (say) 30 seconds.

Comment: @MarcB where can I find about this long polling/comet in php /jquery??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

Over the top of my head, I can think of a trigger that is associated with the table update and that calls the service whenever the "data availability" state changes.

Using this, you will first send a request to check for data. If there is not data available, you can avoid sending multiple requests and just wait for a notification that data is available (until you decide to time out)

In java, this can be done using Hibernate and SQL triggers. [Database trigger and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980875/database-trigger-and-hibernate)